# Can there be an exception thrown by entity framework after an entity has been saved

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a retry mechanism in place that when an exception is thrown by ObjectContext.SaveChanges there will be another call to ObjectContext.SaveChanges.

Now I have some rare cases where an entry is saved multiple times (resulting in multiple entries in the database).

The only reason I can think of is that the call to the database in entity framework works and after that an exception is thrown inside of SaveChanges. Is that possible? The application where this happens is a WepApi project. It does not have async methods.

Comment: Do you have a log of the exceptions?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Are you sure it is you retry mechanism? Are you able to reproduce? No matter what, I strongly advise to add logging to your application.

Comment: It actually only happens only a couple of times a year and the old logs are gone :-(

Comment: Why don't you add a `unique` constraint to that table and catch the DBExeption for that?. Or why don't you implement a check if exists?, or if you get the last modified date... there are many approaches to solve this.